# Can I cancel a TeamCity build from my msbuild script?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

TeamCity allows me to report back from my MsBuild script using the **##teamcity** interaction. I can use this to tell TeamCity that the build has FAILED, or indeed SUCCEEDED, however I would like to tell it to CANCEL the build instead. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I can use this to inform TeamCity of failure...

```
<Message Text="##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE']" Condition="Something==SomeCondition" />
```

I would love to do this...

```
<Message Text="##teamcity[buildStatus status='CANCEL']" Condition="Something==SomeCondition" />
```

I've tried out the [TeamCity Service Tasks](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) but nothing thus far.

**EDIT:**

So it seems this feature is not available, although a [workaround http request](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP) can be used to cancel a build. There is also a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-5567#content-tab=0) for Cancelling a build the TC website.

Comment: See my answer for TeamCity 2019.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to JetBrains [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-5567#comment=27-644381) and [release page](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/02/welcome-teamcity-2019-1-eap1/), since **TeamCity 2019.1 EAP 1** builds can be stopped with service message as in:

```
##teamcity[buildStop comment='canceling comment' readdToQueue='true']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the undocumented http request which has changed since [it was originally posted](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD5/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP). You now need "operationKind=1". I used a powershell runner like so:

```
$buildId = %teamcity.build.id%
$uri = "http://teamcity/ajax.html?guest=1&comment=Cancelling+build+for+some+reason&submit=Stop&buildId=$buildId&kill&operationKind=1"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $uri
```

Another SO post can tell you how to [make an http request from MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339632/make-an-http-request-from-msbuild-script)

The "guest=1" means I'm using the guest account, which at minimum needs the "Stop build / remove from queue" for the project you're going to cancel.

Answer (score 2):

Since Teamcity 8.1 ([Source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-5567#comment=27-644381)) it is possible to Cancel the Build via REST API.

Taken from the 9.x [Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildCanceling/Stopping), cancelling a currently running build

```
curl -v -u user:password --request POST "http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/builds/<buildLocator>" --data "<buildCancelRequest comment='' readdIntoQueue='false' />" --header "Content-Type: application/xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use the [Error task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx), this should cause the execution of the build to stop.

Comment: Yeah I currently use this to stop the build but we want the behaviour within TC to be the same as hitting the Cancel button.