# Make an HTTP request from MSBuild script

Tags: msbuild

I'm looking for a way to hit a web app/restful service URL from msbuild script to trigger remote procedure.
Is there any way how I can do that except calling that external app?
Ideally I'm looking for a way to break a build sequence if service returned something else that http 200

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use the [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) a lot. They add extra tasks for MSBuilds. In there is a HttpRequest task which, from the look of it, does what you want.

```
<HttpRequest Url="http://<mydomain.com>/index.php?checkdb=1" 
                EnsureResponseContains="Database upgrade check completed successfully." 
                FailOnNon2xxResponse="true" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks this one works, I have updated MSbuild Community URL since they have moved to Github.

Answer (score 9):

In version 4 of the MSBuild Community Tasks, the `HttpRequest` task was replaced by **[HttpWebRequest](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/7e2d4a1e-f79a-1b80-359a-445ffdea2ac5.htm)** with a different syntax:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.HttpWebRequest
        TaskAction="GetResponse" Url="http://www.freetodev.com">
    <Output TaskParameter="Response" ItemName="ResponseDetail"/>
    <Output TaskParameter="Status" PropertyName="ResponseStatus"/>
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.HttpWebRequest>
```

Comment: Both answers are good, but I like this one better since I need to use the actual Response message and just show Warning if something goes wrong and check the next sites, etc. Meanwhile other task trows error. Which is not good in my case. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Major I'm glad you found my answer useful :)