# How can I set teamcity properties from within msbuild

Tags: teamcity

The title is very clear. Are there service messages, that allow to modify the content of a teamcity property permanently?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) and call it using MSBuild community tasks as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339632/make-an-http-request-from-msbuild-script).