# How can I download an external project in Visual Studio at build time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am writing a Windows Desktop App in C++. There is an external library that has code that is only available on GitHub. I am now looking for a way to automatically download the library when my Visual Studio project builds so that I do not have to manually download the library on every PC that I debug my application on (at least 3, since it is a shared project).

In CMake I have stumbled upon ExternalProject_Add(), is there anything similar to this for a Visual Studio project?
My solution now is to integrate the library as a git submodule, but it feels like there has to be a better way. I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: So you don't want to use CMake with Visual Studio??

Comment: @drescherjm I could, but my project is already configured as a Visual Studio Project and I figured porting to cmake might be a bit of a hassle

Comment: At the very least you should be able to make http request from msbuild by doing something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339632/make-an-http-request-from-msbuild-script in the project file. Currently not at my computer but I will try writing up something more detail when I get home. You should be able to use package reference to add the community tasks and then from there you can use the xml in the post.

Comment: why is this tagged "cmake" if you _don't_ want to use CMake?

Comment: @TaylorBrown in addition to what Minxin Yu said, this does give me a good idea on how to get started. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio integrates Nuget and VCPKG for library management.

In addition, you can also use your own scripts in Visual Studio:
Project properties -> Build Events -> Pre-Build Events.
Create a powershell file in project and execute it before building the project.

Eg.

Pre-Build Events Command Line: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "test.ps1"`

check if there is an opencv folder in the current folder, if not, download it from GitHub.

test.ps1:

```
$folderExists = (Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_ -like "*opencv*" }).Count -gt 0

if ($folderExists) {
    Write-Host "opencv exists"
} else {
    Write-Host "opencv do not exist"
    git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

}
```