# How to mark TeamCity build as "Canceled"

Tags: build, teamcity

There is an ability to mark buils as successful or failed, but i need to mark TeamCity build as "Canceled" for deattach vcs changes. Now i have to delete failed builds to release their changes. But may be there is some trick to mark as "Canceled"?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel a build from the GUI, manually. I guess you know that and are asking about how to do this programmatically. Indeed, there is a [service message for setting the build status](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatus), but no good way to do this for Cancel.

The closest to a solution I've found is [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064681/1540600). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I saw all of tow these solutions, but first- not for my , second- has no effect, build still in old status. Even in TC database tables no changes after second operation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this should work: make a POST request to `http://TEAMCITY/app/rest/builds/id:BUILD_ID`, sending the following XML as the request's data:

`<buildCancelRequest comment='' readdIntoQueue='false' />`

Comment: No effect. Even in TC database table "build_state" nothing has been changed.
Here a request i was posted:
"curl -Method POST -Uri "http://teamcity:8008/app/rest/builds/id:2707" -Body "<buildCancelRequest comment='' readdIntoQueue='true' />" -ContentType "application/xml""

Comment: What does the TC server log contain? Perhaps you'll find an exception there (could be due to TC permissions; not every user has the privilege to cancel builds).

Comment: ,2 sferencik, No reaction in log files. Or i didn't find. Here is part of output after scriptt was executed:  
_StatusCode : 200 StatusDescription : OK Content : <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Log in to TeamCity &mdash; TeamCity</title> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/ _  
Seems scrip hangs on login screen. What i must to do next?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell. And "Invoke-WebRequest". There is no key "-u", but "-Credentials". I tryed to push login and type my pw in opened windows auth window. No effect. Still recieving "<title>Log in to TeamCity &mdash; TeamCity</title> "/ @sferencik

Comment: Can you verify with curl, as you did above?

Comment: Command:  
curl http://teamcity:8008/app/rest/builds/id:2700 -d "<buildCancelRequest comment='' readdIntoQueue='true'/>" -u login:pass -H "Content-Type:application/xml"
Answer: 
Error has occurred during request processing (Bad Request).
Error: jetbrains.buildServer.server.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Cannot cancel not running build.
Invalid request. Please check the request URL and data are correct.

Comment: Is 2700 the build ID as seen in the URL of the (running) build? When the build finishes, you can also see it in the `teamcity.build.id` parameter. (As opposed to the build number, which is stored in the `build.number` parameter.)

Comment: Yes, "2700" is a build id. And build was finished. It is NOT a running build.

Comment: You can only cancel a running build. Once a build is finished (regardless of the outcome) I don't believe you can set it to cancelled.