# TeamCity - how to combine VCS Triggers

Tags: teamcity

Here is the situation: in git repo I have 3 folders:
A
B
C
If changes were made to A or C, build must be started. In any other case, if changes were made to B as well, it should not be started. How to achieve such behavior with TeamCity VCS Trigger(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found the way to **"prevent build from start if there are changes in particular folder"**. Build will be started. But I decided to make the workaround and skip actual execution of next steps if the changes in B folder have been detected. Below is the script which gives me environment variable to gracefully avoid next build steps execution.

This script is based on TeamCity environment variable

%system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file%

IMPORTANT: don't use -:B (in my case -:lisp) trigger rule, otherwise you will not be able to detect changes in this folder from script.

The script:

```html
#!/bin/bash          

listFiles=$(echo %system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file%)
echo "List files from $listFiles"
echo "--------------------------"
cat $listFiles
echo "--------------------------"
lispFound=$(cat $listFiles | grep -c '^src\/lisp\/*.')
echo "LISP CHANGES WERE DETECTED: $lispFound time(s)"
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.LISP_CHANGES_DETECTED' value ='$lispFound']"
```

As the result, the %env.LISP_CHANGES_DETECTED% with number of changed files will be available at any next step. In my case next step is Ant, and can detect in any target if should just echo "nothing to do" and go out. Here is the exmple of execution log:

[image]

IMPROVEMENT:
As described here [Can I cancel a TeamCity build from my msbuild script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125624/can-i-cancel-a-teamcity-build-from-my-msbuild-script)

Execution may be gracefully stopped right from the script, you will need to add call to cancel execution:

```html
curl -v -u user:password --request POST "http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/builds/<buildLocator>" --data "<buildCancelRequest comment='' readdIntoQueue='false' />" --header "Content-Type: application/xml"
```

Comment: I have problems with a similar setup. Like detecting changes in  merged branches. The additional time a build costs, even when it has to do nothing. Triggering dependend finished build triggers can bring new complexities. Although the solution works, i wanted to note it’s not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure VCS trigger rules for that VCS root.
Add VCS trigger [as usual](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers) and then add this to the rules:

```
-:B/**
```

This will trigger for everything in your VCS root, except folder **B**.
Or you could do it differently and trigger the build only for the changes in **A** or **C** folder:

```
+:A/**
+:C/**
```

That will work because

> When entering rules, please note that as soon as you enter any "+"
>   rule, TeamCity will remove the default "include all" setting. To
>   include all the files, use "+:." rule.

Comment: Does such configuration mean that if changes will be in B and A it will not be triggered?Actually, I need somehow to configure, let say rule, "if there are changes in B - don't start the build, whatever changes are in other folders".

Comment: In case changes would be in both **A** *and* **B**, Teamcity will trigger the build. And this is correct, as if **A** contains some source information, which should be build, skipping it would be incorrect.
Anyway, what you can do is:
1. Filter by user: if folder **B** is going to be modified only by, say, bot user, you can skip it like this: -:user=bot-user;root=VcsRootName:B/**
2. Filter by comment regex: -:comment=Autogenerated, skip build:B/**

Comment: No such option, different users, different comments, but build should be started only if there are no changes in folder B. For changes in folder B another build should be started. Any other ideas?

Comment: @VitalyShulgin, can you provide more information about those builds? Do they test something or compiling binaries?
Again, in my eyes if build #1 is responsible for building folder **A** -- it must be executed.
Is some other build #2 must build only folder **B** -- configure it so.
Right now it's quite difficult to understand your situation, would be nice if you could provide more insight information.

Comment: Sure, folder B contain Common LISP code. If it is changed, the build which will do CL -> C translation must be started and it works fine. When translation finished, next step of build will commit translated C code, and it goes to folders A and C. And as soon as code committed, new build must be started to compile C/C++ code in folder A and C. Beside this, changes may be done to folders A and C by developers directly. And in such case build must be started if there are no changes in folder B, otherwise we must wait while 1st build do the translation. Dependencies and chains are not an options.

Comment: @VitalyShulgin, okay, now it's becomes more clear. One more question: when a developer commits Common List code to folder **B** and C code to **A/C**, does his changes in C code depend on CL? I mean, would the build will fail if you won't do translation first?

Comment: his changes in C on LISP may depend and may NOT :), and build may fail and may not without translation. But, I found my own solution - build will be started, but I gracefully skip the next step. Can not find more elegant solution. See below.